# Docker - Cannot start or stop container groups through Docker Dashboard

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and have been running the Example Voting App (suggested by the getting-started guide).

I have encountered an issue where i can start and stop each individual container within the desktop dashboard, but no start or stop command is passed when i start or stop the containers as a group. I get no logs and no other helpful information as to why this is happening.

I can start and stop the containers as a group from command line by simply navigating to the repository folder and calling docker-compose start/stop, but i'd like the functionality to be able to do it from the desktop dashboard.

Some other things that I have encountered that may* relate to the issue:

> 1. I encountered issues with the dashboard GUI not properly displaying when containers were deleted.
> 2. I had to enable file sharing on my C Drive to even be able 'import' half of the repository files. This was not listed as something that
>      you needed to do on the getting-started guide so im assuming it
>      shouldnt actually be a necessary thing to do.

= Windows 10 =